# Unable to assign $scope after routing to partial template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to make a website that loads all of the necessary template upon the first time visiting the website. I only have one partial template but want to add more eventually. However, even with just this one template I can't get the data i receive from my api to bind into my html.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="tophueApp">
        <body>
            <div ng-view></div>

            <script type="text/ng-template" id="two_column.html">
                <div id="two_column_container">
                    <div id="left_pane">
                    <div class="material_background">
                        <div ng-repeat="post in posts" class="post_block">
                            <a href="/post/{{post.pk}}/{{post.url_safe_title}}" class="title_text" onclick="return     show_inline(this,'{{post.source_site}}')">
                                <span ng-if="post.is_NSFW" class="is_NSFW">
                                    NSFW
                                </span>

                                {{post.title}}
                            </a>
                <span class="post_info">
                    </span>
                </span>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </script>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
            <script src="base.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
        </body>
    </html>
```

**base.js**

```
var tophueApp = angular.module('tophueApp', ['ngRoute']);

tophueApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/topic/:topicName/', {
        templateUrl: 'two_column.html',
        controller: 'TopicController'
      }).
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'two_column.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                     enabled: true,
                     requireBase: false
              });
  }]);

tophueApp.controller('TopicController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $http.get('/api/topic/'+$routeParams.topicName+'/').success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
    });
}]);

tophueApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/home.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
    });
}]);
```

So when i go to a page that is `/topic/topicname` I get the correct json response from my api but it doesn't bind over to the partial template.

**EDIT: (json response)**

```
[{
        "user" : "jack",
        "source_id" : "rX5n0oP",
        "topic" : "swag",
        "title" : "http://i.imgur.com/rX5n0oP.jpg",
        "url_safe_title" : "httpiimgurcomrx5n0opjpg",
        "is_NSFW" : false,
        "source_url" : "http://i.imgur.com/rX5n0oP.jpg",
        "pk" : 8,
        "source_site" : "imgur-img"
    }, {
        "user" : "jack",
        "source_id" : "QW8Sp1O",
        "topic" : "swag",
        "title" : "http://imgur.com/QW8Sp1O",
        "url_safe_title" : "httpimgurcomqw8sp1o",
        "is_NSFW" : false,
        "source_url" : "http://imgur.com/QW8Sp1O",
        "pk" : 1,
        "source_site" : "imgur-img"
    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the angular.js tags were conflicting with my django backend tags. I added

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
```

to change what angular.js looked for and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I can get your templates to bind to $scope by replacing your api calls with static json, see this pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EazprP

```
$scope.posts=[{
    title:"Home"
}]
```

Maybe your json response is throwing it off? Can you post the json?

Comment: i added in the json response from the api

Comment: I can get the controller to be called and set scope.posts equal to my json object but it doesn't change anything in the HTML it just sits there empty - just to clarify

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not changing anything in the html? {{post.title}} = $scope.post.title correct?

Comment: turns out my django backend was getting the tags before angular could on the front end :/ thanks for your help